# how to create a search bar auto fill searchin

Tags: jquery

we are creating an e commerce website in that in UI we kept a search bar in which it have to search the data from database 
for it which it is taking the data from the db

For creating we used following j-query code

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var dataAutoComplete=[];
                var parameters = { search: "Pling" };
                $.get( '/search_product',parameters, function(data) {
                    var dataAutoComplete=[];
                    $.each(data.products,function(index,value){
                        var tempStringJSON=JSON.stringify(dataAutoComplete);
                        if(tempStringJSON.indexOf(value.subcategory+" in "+ value.category)==(-1)){
                            dataAutoComplete.push(value.subcategory+" in "+ value.category);
                        }
                    });
                    $.each(data.products,function(index,value){
                        var tempStringJSON=JSON.stringify(dataAutoComplete);
                        if(tempStringJSON.indexOf(value.brand+" in Brands")==(-1)){
                            dataAutoComplete.push(value.brand+" in Brands");
                        }
                    });
                    $.each(data.products,function(index,value){
                      var tempStringJSON=JSON.stringify(dataAutoComplete);
                        if(tempStringJSON.indexOf(value.product_name+" of "+ value.brand)==(-1)){
                            dataAutoComplete.push(value.product_name+" of "+ value.brand);
                        }

                    });

                  $("#searchBox").autocomplete({
                        source:dataAutoComplete

                    });
                });


                $("#searchBox").on('autocompletechange change',function(){
                    var selectedItem=$(this).val();
                    if(selectedItem.indexOf(" in Brands")!=(-1)){
                        window.location.href = '/prod_grid?brand='+selectedItem.substring(0,selectedItem.indexOf(" in Brands"));
                        index.location.href= '/prod_grid?brand='+selectedItem.substring(0,selectedItem.indexOf(" in Brands"));
                    }
                    else if(selectedItem.indexOf(" in ")!=(-1)){
                        window.location.href = '/prod_grid?prod='+selectedItem.substring(0,selectedItem.indexOf(" in "));

                    }
                    else if(selectedItem.indexOf(" of ")!=(-1)){
                        window.location.href = '/prod_grid?prod='+selectedItem.substring(0,selectedItem.indexOf(" of "))+'&brand='+selectedItem.substring(selectedItem.indexOf(" of ")+4,selectedItem.length);
                    }

                }).change();
```

[image]

The code is working properly but our challenge is [![In the image when we clicked on the select options from db it is auto filling to the search window and from that when we clicked enter then only it is searching the db

Now my requirement is when we selects the data from the drop-down only then it has to directly search not to add the data to window and again clicking 
simply like chrome browser url hitting

Comment: what's `index.location.href` ??

Comment: that is nothing i commented that